# Call multiple Methods(b) within Method(a), and reference variables from Method(a)

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods

I've been writing the same nested for loop over and over with different methods within.  The methods always take the array index as their input parameter.
So I want to write a method for the nested for loop, which can take different methods as an input parameter.  I've never tried to make a method an input parameter.  What I have written below doesn't work, but I hope it conveys the intent of what I am trying to do.

```
    public static void Loop(Func<ModelObject> myMethod)
    {
        for (double PositionX = 0.0; PositionX <= 12000.0; PositionX += 3000.0)
        {
            {
                for (double PositionY = 0.0; PositionY <= 30000.0; PositionY += 6000.0)
                {
                    myMethod(PositionX, PositionY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It gives me a couple errors:

1. "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'PositionX' of 'CreateColumns(double, double)'
2. 'Delegate 'Func<ModelObject>' does not take 2 arguments'

The methods(b) always return a ModelObject type.  However, I guess generics could probably be used if the return type were to change.
This is what my methods(b) look like for reference:

```
    public static ModelObject CreateColumns(double PositionX, double PositionY)
    {
        Beam column = new Beam();
        column.StartPoint = Point(PositionX, PositionY, 0);
        column.EndPoint = Point(PositionX, PositionY, 5000.0);

        column.insert();         
    }
```

So ultimately, I am trying to call CreateColumns within the Loop method, and have the array index passed in as arguments for CreateColumns:

```
 Loop(CreateColumns());
```

This is not working right now.  Does someone know how to make this logic work?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What I've written doesn't work, but I hope it conveys the intent of what I am trying to do.  Do you know how to properly pass a method into another method to make this work?

Comment: You just need `Func<double, double, ModelObject>`  In general the generic args for `Func` are argument types with the last one being the return type.  `<arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argN, retType>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of Loop() to account for the two double parameters of myMethod:

```
 public static void Loop(Func<double, double, ModelObject> myMethod)
 {
        // ...
 }
```

Call Loop() like this:

```
Loop(CreateColumns);
```

Comment: That solved part of the problem.  Now when I try to call Loop(CreateColumns()), it still says "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'PositionX' of 'CreateColumns(double, double)'"

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I added that to the answer.